# Passing a parameter in event binding to component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying a angular project where i need to display n buttons and on click of each button it should display the button number.

Is there a way to pass any static value in event binding which can be used in component for decision making.

```
<button (click)="clicked('want to pass a value here')">Click </button>
<h1>The button number you entered is: {{buttonNumber}}</h1>
```

the values can be: 1, 2... n which will be used for decision making in controller class.

Comment: Sure. Have you tried it?

Comment: as far as i learned i am just familiar with $event, but i don't need any of that details for in my logic

Comment: So did you try the code in your question?

Comment: Typical , you don't need to learn HTML and Javascript, start with Angular2

Comment: yes. i did tried it. may be the declaration of the variable is incorrect

Comment: What variable? What was the actual behavior? What was the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have will work. You need to create a function in your component (in you case called click) and handle the $event that is passed in.

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `
  <h1>The button number you entered is: {{buttonNumber}}</h1>
  <button (click)="clicked('want to pass a value here')">Click</button>
  `
})

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  clicked(yourText) {
    // yourText is the argument from the template
    console.log(yourText)
  }

}
```

Comment: No problem @OnkarGhule! Angular can be a pain to learn but if you stay it daily it will start coming together. Ps. Don't forget to mark this as the answer :)